# Semantic or structure - which should get preference for variable naming?

Tags: naming, variables

We've a call stack in our project. The program is written for microcontroller, the language is C. The call stack is basically an array of integers. The variable that represents this call stack ends with the string `_stack`.

I was reviewing the implementation. The feature is reset recovery, not the call stack, but the call stack is part of the feature. When I first saw the variable, I thought it is used as a stack. So I assumed the following:

- No entries other than the last entry can be accessed.
- There will be PUSH/POP/CLEAR/TOP operations.

Next, I found that the first entry (index 0) is always checked in a special condition. I also found a function where all elements of the array are read sequentially from index 0 to top. Both of them are invalid stack operation.

I am thinking that the variable name should not contain the string `stack` as it is not a stack, rather it is used as a list. But the coder is showing valid logic, that according to semantic meaning, it's a stack and there is in fact PUSH operations.

Should the variable be named with `*stack*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, the difference between calling the structure a `list` which it apparently is and a `stack` which it is effectively being used as, is the debate between [Systems & Apps Hungarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Applications_Hungarian) notation.

Depending on the situation and context, one might be more appropriate than the other. Generally Apps Hungarian provides the reader with a greater context of the use of the variable based on the name alone than Systems Hungarian, thus leading so somewhat self-documenting code.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph: "Generally Apps Hungarian provides the reader with a greater context of the use of the variable based on the name alone than Apps Hungarian". I'm assuming the first is supposed to be Apps Hungarian and the second is supposed to be System notation.

Comment: Sorry, I just woke up...

Comment: No problem. I was going to edit it, since I was pretty sure I knew what you were trying to say, but I wanted to be 100% sure that my assumption was right rather than have a wrong answer.

Answer (score 4):

> [SHUZAN](http://terebess.hu/english/zen.html) held up his staff and waved it before his monks.
>
> "If you call this a staff," he said, "you deny its eternal life. If
>   you do not call this a staff, you deny its present fact. Tell me just
>   what do you propose to call it?"

If it's a variation or embellishment of a stack, I'd be fine with calling it a stack.

But I do hope that there is a bit of commentary or documentation that explains what information it represents, what the normal stack-like operations mean, and why it's necessary to have the others that don't follow the stack discipline.